# How to get selected value on SelectionChanged event of ComboBox in ViewModel (WPF-MVVM)?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I am new in WPF Application with pattern MVVM and I have a particular situation that I do not know how to solve it.

I builted a system to switch environments (Productive, WorkDebug and HomeDebug) with changing only a parameter. I created this system, because every environment have different type Classes and without it, every time that I need to switch environment I have to perform commenct/uncomment on properties and so on.

I have a Class with a switch that handles the execution and determine what type of variable initialize:

```
Private _modalitaEsecuzione As Byte
'DATABASE
Private _ambienteDatabase As AmbienteDatabase
Private _databaseProduttivo As DatabaseProduttivoLinqToSqlDataContext
Private _databaseDebug As DatabaseLinqToSqlDataContext
Private _databaseDebugHome As DatabaseLinqToSqlHomeDataContext

Private _ambienteSettori As AmbienteSettore


Private _ambienteUtente As AmbienteUtente

Private _ambienteProprietaSettore As AmbienteProprietaSettore

Public Sub New(produttivoDebug As Byte)

    _modalitaEsecuzione = produttivoDebug

End Sub
Public Function ImpostaVariabile(tipoFunzione As String)

    Select Case tipoFunzione
        Case "percorsoFilesFilRouge"
            If _modalitaEsecuzione = AmbienteEsecuzioneEnum.Produttivo Then
                Return "productivePath"

            ElseIf _modalitaEsecuzione = AmbienteEsecuzioneEnum.DebugLavoro Then
                Return "workDebugPath"

            Else
                Return "homeDebugPath"

            End If
        Case "databaseConnection"
            If _modalitaEsecuzione = AmbienteEsecuzioneEnum.Produttivo Then

                _ambienteDatabase = New AmbienteDatabase() With {
                    .DatabaseProduttivo = New DatabaseProduttivoLinqToSqlDataContext(ConfigurationManager.
                    ConnectionStrings("productiveConnection").ToString())
                }
                Return _ambienteDatabase

            ElseIf _modalitaEsecuzione = AmbienteEsecuzioneEnum.DebugLavoro Then

                _ambienteDatabase = New AmbienteDatabase() With {
                        .DatabaseDebugLavoro = New DatabaseLinqToSqlDataContext(MySettings.Default.DebugConnection)
                }
                Return _ambienteDatabase
            Else
                _ambienteDatabase = New AmbienteDatabase() With {
                    .DatabaseDebugHome = New DatabaseLinqToSqlHomeDataContext(ConfigurationManager.
                    ConnectionStrings("HomeDebugConnection").ToString())
                }

                Return _ambienteDatabase
            End If
        Case "listaSettori"
            If _modalitaEsecuzione = AmbienteEsecuzioneEnum.Produttivo Then
                _ambienteSettori = New AmbienteSettore() With {
                    .SettoriProduttivo = New ObservableCollection(Of T_Settore)(_ambienteDatabase.DatabaseProduttivo.
                    T_Settore.Where(Function(s) s.NSET_Disponibilita > 0).
                    OrderBy(Function(s) s.TSET_Descrizione).ToList())
                }
                Return _ambienteSettori

            ElseIf _modalitaEsecuzione = AmbienteEsecuzioneEnum.DebugLavoro Then
                _ambienteSettori = New AmbienteSettore() With {
                    .SettoriDebugLavoro = New ObservableCollection(Of T_Settore_Debug)(_ambienteDatabase.
                    DatabaseDebugLavoro.
                    T_Settore_Debug.Where(Function(s) s.NSET_Disponibilita > 0).
                    OrderBy(Function(s) s.TSET_Descrizione).ToList())
                }

                Return _ambienteSettori
            Else
                _ambienteSettori = New AmbienteSettore() With {
                    .SettoriDebugHome = New ObservableCollection(Of T_Settore_Debug_Home)(_ambienteDatabase.
                    DatabaseDebugHome.
                    T_Settore_Debug_Homes.Where(Function(s) s.NSET_Disponibilita > 0).
                    OrderBy(Function(s) s.TSET_Descrizione).ToList())
                }

                Return _ambienteSettori
            End If
        Case "listaUtenti"
            If _modalitaEsecuzione = AmbienteEsecuzioneEnum.Produttivo Then
                _ambienteUtente = New AmbienteUtente() With {
                    .UtentiDatabaseProduttivo = _ambienteDatabase.DatabaseProduttivo.T_Ospite.ToList()
                }

                Return _ambienteUtente

            ElseIf _modalitaEsecuzione = AmbienteEsecuzioneEnum.DebugLavoro Then

                _ambienteUtente = New AmbienteUtente() With {
                    .UtentiDatabaseDebug = _ambienteDatabase.DatabaseDebugLavoro.Utente_Debug.ToList()
                }

                Return _ambienteUtente
            Else
                _ambienteUtente = New AmbienteUtente() With {
                    .UtentiDatabaseDebugHome = _ambienteDatabase.DatabaseDebugHome.Utente_Debug_Homes.ToList()
                }
                Return _ambienteUtente
            End If
        Case "proprietaSettore"
            If _modalitaEsecuzione = AmbienteEsecuzioneEnum.Produttivo Then
                Dim proprietaSettoreProduttivo = _ambienteDatabase.DatabaseProduttivo.T_Settore.
                    Where(Function(s) s.TSET_Codice Is "SND").
                    SingleOrDefault()
                _ambienteProprietaSettore = New AmbienteProprietaSettore() With {
                    .SettoreProduttivo = proprietaSettoreProduttivo,
                    .CodiceSettore = proprietaSettoreProduttivo.TSET_Codice
                }

                Return _ambienteProprietaSettore

            ElseIf _modalitaEsecuzione = AmbienteEsecuzioneEnum.DebugLavoro Then
                Dim proprietaSettoreDebug = _ambienteDatabase.DatabaseDebugLavoro.T_Settore_Debug.
                    Where(Function(s) s.TSET_Codice Is "INF").
                    SingleOrDefault()
                _ambienteProprietaSettore = New AmbienteProprietaSettore() With {
                    .SettoreDebug = proprietaSettoreDebug,
                    .CodiceSettore = proprietaSettoreDebug.TSET_Codice
                }

                Return _ambienteProprietaSettore
            Else
                Dim proprietaSettoreDebugHome = _ambienteDatabase.DatabaseDebugHome.T_Settore_Debug_Homes.
                    Where(Function(s) s.TSET_Codice Is "INF").
                    SingleOrDefault()

                _ambienteProprietaSettore = New AmbienteProprietaSettore() With {
                    .SettoreDebug = proprietaSettoreDebugHome,
                    .CodiceSettore = proprietaSettoreDebugHome.TSET_Codice
                }

                Return _ambienteProprietaSettore
            End If
        Case "utente"


    End Select
    Return ""
End Function
End Class
```

In my ViewModel I instantiate this class and I set various properties with that object. Now, I have a list of object that is bound to the View and the type of this list depends on the environments that is selected. In this class I have three different type classes properties who corresponds to a specific environment:

```
Public Class AmbienteSettore
    Private _settoriProduttivo As ObservableCollection(Of T_Settore)
    Public Property SettoriProduttivo() As ObservableCollection(Of T_Settore)
        Get
            Return _settoriProduttivo
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As ObservableCollection(Of T_Settore))
            _settoriProduttivo = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _settoriDebugLavoro As ObservableCollection(Of T_Settore_Debug)
    Public Property SettoriDebugLavoro() As ObservableCollection(Of T_Settore_Debug)
        Get
            Return _settoriDebugLavoro
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As ObservableCollection(Of T_Settore_Debug))
            _settoriDebugLavoro = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _settoriDebugHome As ObservableCollection(Of T_Settore_Debug_Home)
    Public Property SettoriDebugHome() As ObservableCollection(Of T_Settore_Debug_Home)
        Get
            Return _settoriDebugHome
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As ObservableCollection(Of T_Settore_Debug_Home))
            _settoriDebugHome = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Function GetSettori()
        Return SettoriProduttivo
    End Function
End Class
```

In my ViewModel I declare a property of this class to determine what kind of list. This properties is bound with the combobox and I use a Converter to determine the list type and then to pass it to the XAML that it will be able to manage the list properly.
The Converter convert the object to their right list (Productive, WorkDebug and HomeDebug):

```
    Public Class ListaSettoriConverter
        Implements IValueConverter

        Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
            value = DirectCast(value, AmbienteSettore)
            If value.SettoriProduttivo IsNot Nothing Then
                Return value.SettoriProduttivo
            ElseIf value.SettoriDebugLavoro IsNot Nothing Then
                Return value.SettoriDebugLavoro
            Else
                Return value.SettoriDebugHome
            End If
        End Function

        Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.ConvertBack
            Throw New NotImplementedException()
        End Function

    End Class
```

To intercept the SelectionChanged I need to link a single object of the list with a single property in my ViewModel. This property has the same logic of the list: I have different type classes based on environment.
The class of the single property is

```
Public Class AmbienteProprietaSettore

Private _settoreProduttivo As T_Settore
Public Property SettoreProduttivo() As T_Settore
    Get
        Return _settoreProduttivo
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As T_Settore)
        _settoreProduttivo = value

    End Set
End Property

Private _settoreDebug As T_Settore_Debug
Public Property SettoreDebug() As T_Settore_Debug
    Get
        Return _settoreDebug
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As T_Settore_Debug)
        _settoreDebug = value
    End Set
End Property
Private _settoreDebugHome As T_Settore_Debug_Home
Public Property SettoreDebugHome() As T_Settore_Debug_Home
    Get
        Return _settoreDebugHome
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As T_Settore_Debug_Home)
        _settoreDebugHome = value


    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

This is the XAML ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200" Margin="5 0 0 0" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AmbienteSettore, Converter={StaticResource ListaSettoriConverter}}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=AmbienteProprietaSettore, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                    Converter={StaticResource SettoreConverter}}"
```

The question is, how can I manage the NotifyPropertyChanged of a property that is inside a property of the ViewModel? Because the binding is based on the class which has the right properties set inside it.

I hope that is clear and thanks in advance

Comment: I think messing up your code with binding converters all over the place just to make the view to adapt to the selected environment is a very bad idea. Also the logic to select the environment should not be part of the view model. Instead you should select the environment in your *App.xaml.cs*. You must bootstrap your application: **1)** Create a dedicated `MainViewModel` for each environment **2)** Select the proper environment `MainViewModel` (like `WorkDebugMainViewModel`) on start up and **3)** inject it into the constructor of your `MainWindow` **4)** Now, show the `MainWindow` manually

Comment: **5)** Let `MainWindow` host the content using a `ContentPresenter` that binds its `Content` property to the `MainWindow.DataContext` by defining an implicit `DataTemplate` for each environment view model. This way WPF will pick the correct view based on the `DataTemplate` automatically and all data bindings will work correctly without any converters (as they now target explicitly a particular view model data type of the corresponding `DataTemplate`. In other words: you must swap in and out the complete `DataContext` when you start your application. This is easier to maintain too.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I only have two converter and the environment selection is in App.xaml.vb. So, you suggest to have a ViewModel for every type of environment? Like: MainWindowViewModelProductive, MainViewModelWorkDebug and so on, with the same logic apart the property, where I will change the class type?

Comment: Your original problem is difficult to understand. What do you mean by changing the class type? Beside that, You can move this property to an interface. Then move the shared code to a common base class. Then let each view model extend this base class and implement the property. But why do you have to change the type of a property?

Comment: When I am in Productive environment, I have a Class named "T_Osp" with several properties and when I am in Debugging environment I have a similar Class, with the same purpose of the productive environment class, named "Ute", with different properties. That is why when I work on these environments I have different databases to work with. So I mean that in ViewModelDebug I have class type "Ute" and in ViewModelProductive the class is different type "T_Osp" and the problem come when inside the code i have to work with that property, the class that I use in Debug is different from the Productive

Comment: Alright, I see. In this case you should not use a concrete type for your property. For example let `T_Osp` and `Ute` implement the same interface e.g. `IRepository`. The `IRepository` interface must define all the common members that you will bind to. Then make the property of this interface type. Now your binding will work no matter the implementing type i.e. whether you assign `T_Osp` or `Ute` to this property. This technique is called Dependency Inversion ( the "D" in "SOLID", known as the SOLID principles), in case you want to learn more about it or search the web for examples.

Comment: Alternatively extract the database part to new classes `DesignRepository` and `ProductionRepository`, where each uses a different DB. Let both classes implement a common interface `IRepository`. Then use a single class for the property e.g. `RepositoryViewModel`. This class has a constructor that requests a `IRepository` implementation. Then pass the proper repository implementation constructor. Now `RepositoryViewModel` will use automatically the correct database, since it only sees an `IRepository` that it will use to perform all operations against the anonymous database.

Comment: In case it is only the database that changes, I would recommend the second solution.

Comment: Nice, I understood and I will examine in depth the concepts. Thank you for your help!